# C'è una consolidata espressione metaforica per "una ricerca che si rivelerà una perdita di tempo perché l'oggetto ricercato non esiste o è altrove"?

Tags: word-choice

Ho pensato a questo quando mi è capitato di leggeere l'espressione [wild goose chase](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese-italiano/wild-goose-chase).

Mi chiedo se c'è in italiano un'espressione, magari totalmente diversa, ma comunque metaforica, per esprimere lo stesso concetto.

Ho pensato a "caccia alle streghe", ma ho l'impressione che questa espressione, dati i trascorsi storici, avrebbe l'effetto collaterale di connotare la ricerca come qualcosa di negativo in senso morale.

Forse "caccia ai fantasmi" non avrebbe lo stesso problema, ma non l'ho mai sentito.

---

Mia madre mi ha suggerito "ricerca del Santo Graal". Penso che sia particolarmente calzante, ma non la posto come risposta in quanto non so quanto sia consolidata. Non sono stato in grado di cercarne utilizzi altro che letterali.

Comment: Una espressione che si usa è 'andare alla ricerca dell'Araba Fenice', ma va bene solo in alcuni casi,  non è prprio come 'wild goose chase', perché dà a quello che si cerca una connotazione troppo positiva e mitica.

Comment: “Caccia alle streghe” in effetti è troppo connotato in tutt'altro senso, sia che si pensi alle “vere” presunte streghe, sia all'uso per riferirsi al maccartismo. Per giunta, dal punto di vista dei “cacciatori”, la ricerca non era una perdita di tempo, perché eliminavano donne scomode e comunisti, rispettivamente.

Comment: Un'altra espressione che mi viene in mente è 'acchiappare le mosche', per dire  'fare una cosa inutile', sta anche nel link qui si seguito, ma nella versione 'pigliar mosche' che non ho mai sentito usare: https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/M/mosca.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Ho trovato sul dizionario "Ragazzini":

"to lead somebody on a wild-goose chase": menare qualcuno per il naso.

Le traduzioni di "wild-goose chase" non sono interessanti:

- impresa inutile
- tentativo assurdo
- cosa impossibile.

Comment: In effetti, a differenza di altri dizionari, purtroppo il Ragazzini non distingue graficamente i possibili traducenti dalle espressioni che si limitano a spiegare il termine inglese.

Answer (score 1):

"Cercare un ago in un pagliaio" mi sembra abbastanza attinente. Il significato è più quello di una ricerca difficile, invece che inutile, però si riferisce espressamente al cercare.